# Facing crash in clr.dll in different web applications

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection, clr

We are facing crash in clr.dll in different web applications:

Below is the stack trace from dump created by Windows Event Viwer:

```
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 000000f1`be14daa0 00007fff`26d3a651 clr!SVR::gc_heap::mark_object_simple+0x2f7
01 000000f1`be14db00 00007fff`26d3585f clr!SVR::GCHeap::Promote+0xe1
02 000000f1`be14db80 00007fff`26d31be7 clr!GcInfoDecoder::EnumerateLiveSlots+0x1391
03 000000f1`be14e000 00007fff`26d317fe clr!GcStackCrawlCallBack+0x307
04 000000f1`be14e420 00007fff`26d3938a clr!GCToEEInterface::GcScanRoots+0x469
05 000000f1`be14f8e0 00007fff`26d38af7 clr!SVR::gc_heap::mark_phase+0x1de
06 000000f1`be14f980 00007fff`26d38d66 clr!SVR::gc_heap::gc1+0xa7
07 000000f1`be14f9d0 00007fff`26d384f0 clr!SVR::gc_heap::garbage_collect+0x870
08 000000f1`be14fa70 00007fff`26d61cc7 clr!SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function+0x74
09 000000f1`be14faa0 00007fff`26d62a14 clr!SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub+0x7e
0a 000000f1`be14fce0 00007fff`301c13d2 clr!GCThreadStub+0x24
0b 000000f1`be14fd10 00007fff`303254f4 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
0c 000000f1`be14fd40 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34

---------------------------------------
```

Below is message from Event Viewer:
    ---------------------------------------

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3468.0, time stamp: 0x5d490db7
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000a1cc3
Faulting process id: 0x3ebc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5b9bc8b6eaefd
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 7b34e833-25c0-11ea-8122-0050569d7719
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFF26D41CC3 (00007FFF26CA0000) with exit code 80131506.

-------------------------------
```

We have tried below settings in aspnet.config file at below path:

```
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
    <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>

%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Aspnet.config
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Aspnet.config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
    <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true" />
    <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false" />
    <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
    <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true" />
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
    <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>
  </runtime>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
  <system.web>
    <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="3000" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="3000" />
  </system.web>
  <performanceScenario value="HighDensityWebHosting" />
</configuration>

-------------------
```

Comment: Please guide, if any other information is required here for valuable comments to resolve this. Thanks.